# How to open pdf files inside a pane in tmux?

Tags: tmux, pdf, zathura

I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome Desktop. My pdf app is zathura and currently using tmux. I was wondering is it possible to show pdf file in another pane in tmux?

Comment: What do you mean by 'show the pdf file in another pane'? terminals can't show a pdf file...

Comment: Hello and Welcome to the Unix & Linux Stack.  While I've provided an answer, it's primary "negative", with some explanation.  If it helps you understand the *why* behind this, then consider upvoting and accepting it as the answer.  **However**, please check back here every so often.  There's always the chance that I'm completely wrong and that someone else has figured out a way to do this.  It may be hours, days, weeks, or longer before they see your question and respond.  So check back every so often to see if things have changed.  You can always accept a new answer in place of mine.  Thanks!

Comment: @mattb well, english is not my first language. I am used to linux environment. You had two options, either try to help with a solution or be pedantic about semantics. You chose the latter. Either way, the point was, what is the equivalent of ueberzug, which is used for images, but now for pdf files and on top of that show it in tmux panes. NotTheDr01ds gave me an answer and I agree with his reasoning.

Comment: @llesh I didn't mean to come across as pedantic (and not my downvote btw) - I
didn't know about things like ueberzug. I thought terminals could only display
text characters. My ignorance on this point led my to assume you couldn't
really be asking for how to display pdf in a terminal (since I though 'everyone
knew' that's impossible). Now I see that it's a perfectly reasonable question.
I tried to second guess what you might be asking, but I couldn't think of
anything so my original comment probably unintentionally came across as a bit short/mocking.

Comment: @mattb no offense taken. I should have put more context. Problem is, whenever I do this, the question becomes convoluted since I am not a native speaker. In simplicity lies clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to give a "negative answer" without at least providing a workaround or alternative suggestion of some sort.

But in this case, given the specific use-case you are asking about, the answer is simply "No, there is currently no way to display graphical (non-text) output in a Tmux pane."

Tmux communicates with whatever terminal you are using [escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).  This gives it a lot of control over the terminal buffer, but there are no standardized escape codes that allow graphical output within the terminal.

There are some [terminal alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/q/97542/1165986) that appear to display graphics (not necessarily PDFs), but these are non-standard, so Tmux isn't going to know how to interface with them.

For instance, I decided to check out `w3m` with `w3m-img` to see what would happen in a Tmux pane.  `w3m-img` works by trying to figure out "where" in the terminal the cursor is and drawing an image *over* that location in X, rather than truly *in* the terminal.

When invoked in a Tmux pane that was split-to-the-right, `w3m` with `w3m-img` painted the graphics for the web-page over the *left* pane instead.

I don't believe you'll have any better success with other workarounds or alternatives.

My best recommendation here is to just use the terminal/Tmux for its primary purpose (CLI) and X applications for graphical output.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't know exactly what you're asking for, but

`pdftotext -layout file.pdf - | less`

does a reasonable job of converting a PDF to text -- which you can display in a terminal.